# Where is the Android Notepad sample?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, code-documentation

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase says

> See the Notepad sample application in the SDK for an example of creating and managing a database

The page provides no link. However if I use the Search facility on the same page the first search result is

> developer.android.com/guide/samples/NotePad/index.html

But when I follow that link I get

> 404 Page not found

Googling has led me to the same dead end.

I'm looking for a simple tutorial on how to execute a simple database query.

Comment: Search your pc instead.

Comment: Sorry. I don't understand. Where on my PC should I search? Do you mean that the Android installation will have included the sample? If so, I haven't found it.

Comment: Yes there will be an examples directory in the sdk stuff on your pc. For every sdk version another examples directory. Check if you downloaded them using android studio sdk manager.

Comment: I've found the SDK Location: C:\Users\[myname]\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk, but I can't find any Notepad or, indeed, any folder of Samples or Examples or Tutorials.

Comment: [John David Molina](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14744228) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65096811) saying "See the following link for the source of notepad https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/05523fb0b48280a5364908b00768ec71edb847a2/samples/NotePad/src/com/example/android/notepad"

Comment: Thanks, Scratte and John David Molina.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google has not led you to dead end. However they have shifted the repository to the https://android.googlesource.com/

All those samples are available here :

> https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/05523fb0b48280a5364908b00768ec71edb847a2/samples/

The notepad sample can be found here :

> https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/05523fb0b48280a5364908b00768ec71edb847a2/samples/NotePad/